# Nodejs - .node_libraries/ for www-data

Tags: php, node.js

I want to use uglifyjs (https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) from my PHP application. UglifyJS is built using Nodejs, so I need a .node_libraries/ dir in my homedir (/home/peppe).

I want to execute uglifyjs by shell_exec() in PHP. But where am I supposed to add the .node_libraries/ dir since www-data user doesn't have a home dir?

---

Addition: I solved it. The solution was to set NODE_PATH and execute the command like this in PHP:
`shell_exec('NODE_PATH="/opt/www_node_libraries/"; export NODE_PATH; uglifyjs options filename');`

Comment: Hey Erik, it's alright to make an answer and mark it as a solution to your question, I don't think anyone will hold it against you ;)

Comment: Please move your solution down to an answer so we can get this off the unanswered list.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the OP and @Bill so we can get this removed from unanswered list.

> Addition: I solved it.
>   The solution was to set NODE_PATH and execute the command like this in PHP:

```
shell_exec('NODE_PATH="/opt/www_node_libraries/"; export NODE_PATH; uglifyjs options filename');
```