# Uglify-JS won't run using shell_exec()

Tags: php, node.js

My question is similar to this:

[Nodejs - .node_libraries/ for www-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943384/nodejs-node-libraries-for-www-data)

I've been trying all night to get php to execute uglifyjs. I've tried:

```
die(shell_exec('NODE_PATH="/home/app/nodejs/node_modules/"; export NODE_PATH; uglifyjs -o /home/app/public_html/js/profile.min5.js /home/app/public_html/js/profile.js'));
```

and

```
die(shell_exec('node /home/app/nodejs/node_modules/uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs -o /home/app/public_html/js/profile.min33.js /home/app/public_html/js/profile.js'));
```

and a bunch of other crazy combinations but nothing works. Everything works fine if I do it manually in the shell. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried looking at the following (I'll go for the obvious since you haven't said what you've already tried):

user apache/www-data is allowed access to /home/app : sometimes /home directories are closed off (chmod 0700)

Is `safe_mode` on your server in effect? From the command line, try:

```
php -i | grep safe_mode
```

Then, look at the output of:

```
phpinfo();
```

Which version of PHP are you using (might well be irrelevant)?

Comment: The version of PHP is 5.3.5 but I'm not using Apache, I'm using ngnix instead and running php-fpm but the user that php is running on (from running (exec('whoami')) if that helps. Safe mode is off.

Comment: I just tried chmodding and it worked! Thanks so much. I'm not sure if I compromised anything. The command that works is: 

`shell_exec('/usr/bin/node /usr/bin/uglifyjs -o /home/app/public_html/js/profile.min333.js /home/app/public_html/js/profile.js')`

And I chmodded /usr/bin/node and /usr/bin/uglifyjs to 4777 which I'm not sure is a good idea. I also chmodded /home to 777 but I'm the only use on this VPS so I'm thinking its not a big deal but for all I know it could be.

Comment: You could try and move everything out of your /home/app path and into something like /data/app

That way you get to retain your access right on /home/app

Anyway, this works :-)

I don't think you need to chmod the applications. Try it with 755, it should work.